# Error use of parameter outside function body before ']'

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I'm new to the site. I'm sorry for my missing. When I call the print_array function it gives an error. I do not understand why this is happening. Could you please help me?

Thank you for answers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_array(int n,int m,int matrix[][m]){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int m,n;
    while (true){
        cout << "Given row size: " ;
        cin >> n ;
        cout << "Given column size: ";
        cin >> m;
        if (m>=5 && n>=5){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout <<"Row and Column size must be grater than 5. Please try again"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
    int array_A[n][m];

    cout <<"Enter elements by giving a space between them\n"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin >> array_A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    print_array(n,m,array_A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not in standard C++. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I use CLion 2020.2.4 compiler is minGW

Comment: Neither of those is a compiler. I suppose you're using some version of g++?

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of array allocation is a bit wrong. In C++, you can't just dynamically allocate memory for an array as you did with `int array_A[n][m]`. You either have to allocate memory manually using the keyword `new` or use a container that does this for you, like `std::vector`. Since you are starting I'd go with the standard library container.

You could initialize your variable with something like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> array_A(n, std::vector<int>(m, 0))` after including `#include <vector>`. After this, you could simply use your variable as you did and pass it as a parameter of your function.